# Как сделать мгновенную привязку в c#?

Tags: wpf, binding, observer

Передо мной стоит задача: "на лету" видоизменять вводимый текст.

В `textbox` ввожу например текст такого вида `:-)`.

При вводе каждого символа, соответствующее свойство обновляется. Если в веденной комбинации содержится `:-)`,то эти символы мгновенно прeобразуются в  и возвращается на исходное место . При этом мне нужно использовать наблюдатель, чтобы производить то самое преобразование.

vm:

```
 public class CurrentDialogViewModel:ViewModelBase
 { private string _sendingMessageText;
   public string SendingMessageText {
       get { return _sendingMessageText; }

       set
       {
           if (value != null)
           {
               WriteingMessage.NotifyObservers(value);
           }
           _sendingMessageText = Observer.outtext;
             OnPropertyChanged("SendingMessageText");


       }
   }
public Observer Observer = new Observer();
public Observerable WriteingMessage = new Observerable();
public CurrentDialogViewModel(){  WriteingMessage.AddObserver(Observer);}
 }
```

наблюдатель:

```
public  class Observerable
{
    public List<Observer> observers;
    public Observerable()
    {
        observers = new List<Observer>();
    }
    public void AddObserver(Observer o) { observers.Add(o); }
    public void RemoveObserver(int index) { observers.RemoveAt(index); }
    public void NotifyObservers(string text)
    {
        foreach (Observer o in observers)
        {
            o.Notify(text);
        }
    }


}
public class Observer
{   IDictionary<String, String> Smiles { get; set; }
    public string outtext{get;set;}
    public  Observer()
    {

        Smiles = new Dictionary<String, String>();
       Smiles.Add(":-)", "");
       Smiles.Add(":-(", "");
       Smiles.Add(":-D", "");
    }
    public void Notify(string text)
    {
        foreach(var i in Smiles)
       {
           if (text.Contains(i.Key))
           {
               text.Replace(i.Key, i.Value);

           }

       }
        outtext = text;
    }
}
```

}

View:

```
<TextBoxText="{Binding Path=SendingMessageText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Ну отлично. А в чём проблема? Чем ваш текущий код не решает?

Comment: при вводе сообщения" :-)" не меняется на "" в текстбоксе

Comment: Ну, а вы трассировали? У вас есть несколько кусков программы, какой из них не сработал?

Comment: для чего WriteingMessage.NotifyObservers, если есть OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: Таково мое задание,внедрить наблюдатель в эту конструкцию. Спасибо , проблема решилась!

Comment: _"Таково мое задание,внедрить наблюдатель в эту конструкцию"_ -- понятно. как бы ни было, но внедрять в модель Observer  и т.д. - это лишнее, т.к. модель вызывает OnPropertyChanged, т.е. посылает событие PropertyChanged  -- таким образом UI получает уведомление о том, что свойство модели изменилось.

Comment: А как сделать нужно было по-хорошему?
Может, внедрить всю эту конструкцию из наблюдателя в сеттер?Или что-то еще?
По вашему задание некорректно , или есть правильные варианты его решения?

Comment: Увидел в вашем примере, то о чем я говорю

Comment: @Kirill_Levchenko _"есть правильные варианты его решения?"_ -- в model надо сосредоточить вся логику обработки данных. и сделать модель независимой и переносимой. Но т.к. WPF-UI сильно отличается от WinForms-UI, то для привязки UI к модели нужны viewmodel. все остальное - лишнее - убрать, т.к. less is more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, похоже, в `text.Replace(i.Key, i.Value);`.

Строки в C# неизменяемые. Возможно, вы имели в виду `text = text.Replace(i.Key, i.Value);`

---

Обновление: вторая часть ответа не нужна, т. к. за полем `outtext` таки ведётся наблюдение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, проблема решилась и заключалась как раз в  text = text.Replace(i.Key, i.Value);!!!

Comment: @Kirill_Levchenko: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

> чтобы в textbox ввожу текст, например " :-)" и при вводе каждого символа соответствующее свойство обновляется, и если в веденной комбинации содержится :-),то эти символы мгновенно прeобразуются в

Минимальное и достаточное решение для WPF такое.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private void Changed(string name) { 
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        Dictionary<string, string> smiles;
        public Model() {
            this.smiles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            this.smiles.Add(":)", "");
        }
        public string Text {
            get { return _Text; }
            set {
                if (_Text != value) {
                    _Text = value;
                    if(_Text != null)
                        foreach (var kv in smiles)
                            if (_Text.Contains(kv.Key))
                                _Text = _Text.Replace(kv.Key, kv.Value);
                    Changed("Text");
                }
            }
        }
        string _Text;
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            this.DataContext = new Model() { Text = "123" };
        }
    }
}
```

class Model без изменений можно перенести в WinForms.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решилась!

Comment: Я бы всё же переименовал `Model` в `ViewModel`.

Comment: @VladD _"Я бы всё же переименовал Model в ViewModel"_ -- тут model в namespace WpfApplication1 - только для примера. а вообще класс model должен находиться в отдельной сборке, которая может использоваться без ui. и если нет ui, а в названии есть view*, то получается как-то не очень.