# Как получить доступ к элементу управления из другого файла?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть файл `MainWindow.xaml`. В этом файле находится некий элемент управления (например,`Label1`). К решению подключен файл `SomeClass.cs`.

Как из класса `SomeClass` получить доступ к `Label1`?

Comment: Это можно сделать технически, но вам не должно этого хотеться. (Точно так же как вам не должно хотеться дать доступ к приватным полям класса,) Опишите вашу настоящую задачу.

Comment: @VladD,задача в получении содержимого TextBox`а из файла,в котором реализована логика приложения,для последующего очищения поля. Юзер вводит строку в поле,переходит к следующему полю,программа запоминает введенное значение и очищает поле.

Comment: Хорошо, а причём тут сторонний класс? Это по идее внутреннее дело `MainWindow`, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD,в стороннем классе реализуется логика приложения,в MainWindow`е ничего,кроме конструктора нету

Comment: Если это логика приложения, то она не должна лезть в `MainWindow`. Она должна выставлять свойства, к которым `MainWindow` должен биндиться.

Comment: @david_I в MainWindow должна быть UI-логика, а в SomeClass должна быть только бизнес-логика. поэтому передавать в SomeClass ссылку на Label1 не надо.

Comment: @VladD,и все же,как можно сохранить содержимое TextBox`a для последующего доступа к нему из внешнего класса?

Comment: @david_I посмотрите пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476228/#476234). class Model  это как ваш SomeClass.

Comment: @david_I: Вы должны забиндить свойство `TextBox`'а `Text` на свойство из вашей `ViewModel`'и (в вашем случае — `SomeClass`). Не забудьте реализовать в `SomeClass` интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @VladD,проблема в том,что пользователь должен ввести 5 значений в одно поле,и храниться они должны в разных переменных.на какое событие стоит реагировать для своевременного изменения привязки?

Comment: @david_I таки странное поведение, когда вводят значения в одно поле, а сохранять их надо в разных свойствах. Как вы определяете сейчас, в каком случае куда сохранять?

Comment: @Monk,суть в том,что юзер должен ввести одно значение(к примеру,адрес електронной  почты),перейти к следующему шагу и ввести в УЖЕ ПУСТОЕ поле другую строку( например,пароль).Обе строки должны хранится в разных переменных.Трудность в смене привязки при переходе к следующему шагу

Comment: @david_I а как пользователь переходит к след шагу и получает снова чистое поле? Всмысле, это можно сделать через Frame с Page внутри, тогда в каждом Page будет свой биндинг. Суть в том, что контролы обычно разные (валидация ввода например, закрытый ввод пароля - это врядли делается единым контролом).

Comment: @david_I: Подождите, а как вы собираетесь узнать, что у вас уже закончился первый шаг, и сейчас будет второй?

Comment: @VladD,в разметке присутствует кнопка,при нажатии на которую инкрементируется счетчик шагов,очищается текстовое поле и сохраняется значение поля

Comment: @david_I: Ага, понял. Сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте-ка я приведу вам достаточно большое, полное приложение, которое делает то, что вам надо. Оно написано с MVVM, так что его можно использовать как базу для дальнейшей разработки.

Предупреждаю, кода будет много.

Итак, на самом деле у вас wizard — ввод данных окно за окном с кнопкой Next (и возможно Previous). Учитывая это, напишем общий менеджер визардов.

Но для начала, нам понадобится вспомогательный класс для реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class NotifyPropertyChangedImpl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void NotifyPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Ещё одна вещь, которая нам понадобится — простая реализация `ICommand`:

```
class TrivialCommand : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl, ICommand
{
    public TrivialCommand(Action onExecute) { this.onExecute = onExecute; }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return canExecute; }
    public void Execute(object parameter) { onExecute(); }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecuteProperty
    {
        get { return canExecute; }
        set
        {
            if (canExecute != value)
            {
                canExecute = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange();
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
    bool canExecute;
    Action onExecute;
}
```

(Эти классы должны быть у вас в любом случае в загашнике, если вы программируете на WPF. Или в MVVM-фреймворке, если вы им пользуетесь.)

Название свойства `CanExecuteProperty` не очень хорошее, но я не придумал ничего лучше.

Имея это на руках, определим сам Wizard (точнее, его ViewModel):

```
class WizardVM : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    // это таск, который окончится, когда выполнится OnFinish
    public Task Run()
    {
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    // получаем в конструкторе список объектов, которые мы будем
    // прогонять нашим визардом
    public WizardVM(IEnumerable<object> pages)
    {
        this.pages = pages.ToList();
        onNext = new TrivialCommand(ProcessNext);
        onFinish = new TrivialCommand(ProcessFinish);
        currentIndex = -1;
        ProcessNext();
    }

    // увеличивает currentIndex на 1 и устанавливает остальные данные
    void ProcessNext()
    {
        currentIndex++;
        // переходим к следующей странице в списке
        CurrentPage = pages[currentIndex];
        // если это последняя страница...
        if (currentIndex == pages.Count - 1)
        {
            // то дальше идти нельзя, но можно закончить
            onNext.CanExecuteProperty = false;
            onFinish.CanExecuteProperty = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // иначе дальше идти можно, закончить нельзя
            onNext.CanExecuteProperty = true;
            onFinish.CanExecuteProperty = false;
        }
    }

    void ProcessFinish()
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(0);
        // один раз закончили — больше нельзя
        onFinish.CanExecuteProperty = false;
    }

    // список VM-объектов, представляющих страницы
    List<object> pages;
    // номер текущего объекта, в начале это 0
    int currentIndex;
    // таск, который будет завершён по окончанию работы
    TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    // текущая страница, стандартное свойство с INPC
    object currentPage;
    public object CurrentPage
    {
        get { return currentPage; }
        set { if (currentPage != value) { currentPage = value; NotifyPropertyChange(); } }
    }

    // команда перехода к следующей странице
    TrivialCommand onNext;
    public TrivialCommand OnNext { get { return onNext; } }

    // команда окончания работы
    TrivialCommand onFinish;
    public TrivialCommand OnFinish { get { return onFinish; } }
}
```

Это общий класс, который может работать с чем угодно. Вы ещё можете добавить команду `OnPrevious` аналогичным образом.

Теперь, напишем ещё VM для страницы нашего визарда. Поскольку все страницы одинаковые, мы тут можем обойтись одной VM, но в общем случае вам понадобится их несколько:

```
class SingleInputVM : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    public SingleInputVM(string prompt) { this.prompt = prompt; }

    // строка, описывающая вводимый текст
    readonly string prompt; // не изменяется
    public string Prompt { get { return prompt; } }

    // строка, принимающая ввод (и стандартное INPC-свойство)
    string input;
    public string Input
    {
        get { return input; }
        set { if (input != value) { input = value; NotifyPropertyChange(); } }
    }
}
```

Теперь перейдём к визуальной части. Для начала, нам нужен код, описывающий страницу визарда. Обычно для такого кода нужно создавать отдельный `UserControl`, но мы поместим код как есть. Для привязки к типу используем `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SingleInputVM}">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prompt}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Input, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

(По хорошему его нужно бы поместить в отдельный файл, но я для простоты помещу прямо в общее окно визарда.)

Теперь сам визард. Оформим его в виде стандартного окна:

```
<Window x:Class="InputWizard.WizardWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InputWizard"
        Title="Wizard" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BTV"/>
        <!-- этот шаблон у нас уже был, мы его кладём сюда -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SingleInputVM}">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prompt}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Input, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Это на самом деле хитрая строка. Мы выбираем шаблон в зависимости от 
             фактического типа CurrentPage! -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />

        <!-- А это просто панель с кнопками, ничего особенного -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1">
            <!-- единственная фишка -- когда команда отключена, мы прячем кнопку
                 для этого нам нужен конвертер из bool в Visibility
                 такой есть стандартный, пользуемся им -->
            <Button Command="{Binding OnNext}" Margin="10"
                    Visibility="{Binding OnNext.CanExecuteProperty,
                                         Converter={StaticResource BTV}}">
                Next
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding OnFinish}" Margin="10"
                    Visibility="{Binding OnFinish.CanExecuteProperty,
                                         Converter={StaticResource BTV}}">
                Finish
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Это практически всё! Осталось написать связывающую логику. Для начала, отключим стандартное создание окна в `Application`:

```
<Application x:Class="InputWizard.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

И допишем логику управления в code behind:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // создаём VM-ки страниц визарда
        var inputs = new[]
        {
            new SingleInputVM("Here, input your name"),
            new SingleInputVM("... and now address, please"),
            new SingleInputVM("... and your age, too")
        };

        // создаём VM самого визарда
        var wizard = new WizardVM(inputs);
        // и его окно
        var window = new WizardWindow() { DataContext = wizard };
        // показываем окно...
        window.Show();
        // и ждём, когда работа визарда закончится
        await wizard.Run();
        // закрываем окно
        window.Close();
        // и показываем результат
        MessageBox.Show(
            string.Format(
                "you are {0}, age {2}, live at {1}",
                inputs[0].Input,
                inputs[1].Input,
                inputs[2].Input));
    }
}
```

Теперь точно всё.

Answer (score 1):

У меня получился какой то франкенштейн по вашему описанию.
Класс для данных:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace OneBoxToAllProperty
{
  public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private string smart;
    private int count;

    public string Smart
    {
      get { return smart; }
      set
      {
        smart = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public int Count
    {
      get { return count; }
      set
      {
        count = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        DoSmart();
      }
    }

    public string One { get; set; }

    public string Two { get; set; }

    internal void DoSmart()
    {
      switch (this.Count)
      {
        case 1:
          this.One = this.Smart;
          break;
        case 2:
          this.Two = this.Smart;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      this.Smart = string.Empty;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

И форма, XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="OneBoxToAllProperty.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OneBoxToAllProperty"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Smart}"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Next"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CS к ней:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace OneBoxToAllProperty
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = new SomeClass();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      (this.DataContext as SomeClass).Count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Заполняет свойства по тому, как описана логика в DoSmart, после заполнения обоих полей класса - позволяет впустую кликать дальше =)

Comment: Спасибо за настолько подробный ответ!