# C# ListView MouseDoubleClick MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

Как реализовать в *WPF* событие *MouseDoubleClick* для *ListView*, чтобы при двойном клике по элементу списка вылазило новое окно? Используя паттерн *MVVM*.

Comment: почитайте и посмотрите пример на C# [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482529/196972)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

1. Определите команду в вашей VM (пусть будет `LaunchDetailViewCommand`)
2. Привяжите событие двойного клика к команде:

   ```
   <ListView xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" ...>
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction
                   Command="{Binding Path=LaunchDetailViewCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </Grid>
   ```
3. В команде вы находитесь в VM, активизируйте там новое окно, обычным способом.